# Parameterized SQL in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, .net-3.5, ado.net

If I have code like so:

```
public T ExecuteQuery<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> getResult, string query, params IDataParameter[] parameters)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.DefaultConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // Declare the parameter in the query string
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }

                command.Prepare();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return getResult(dr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetMySpecId(string dataId)
    {
        return ExecuteQuery(
            dr =>
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    return dr[0].ToString();
                }

                return string.Empty;
            },
            @"select ""specId"" from ""MyTable"" where ""dataId"" = :dataId",
            new SqlParameter("dataId", dataId));
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that the

```
new SqlParameter("dataId", dataId));
```

piece of code is passing in a text or maybe an integer? Also how does the `@"select..."` actually work as I'm familiar to:

```
 select id from mytable where dataId = @dataID;
```

Comment: @"select" appears to just be part of a literal string

Comment: so is this parameterized correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's parameterized properly. Take a look at the below modified code that will ensure the parameters are added properly and simplify the construction of the call to `ExecuteQuery` (in my opinion of course). This is pretty straight forward. The select statement is parameterized properly because it's using the `@varname` syntax:

```
"select \"specId\" from \"MyTable\" where \"dataId\" = @dataId"
```

Further, the parameters are typed properly because of the `AddWithValue` method:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
```

Finally, using the dictionary to send in the parameters keeps it pretty simple to construct the parameters from any structure, whether that be parameter values, or even an object.

```
public T ExecuteQuery<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> getResult, string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.DefaultConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Declare the parameter in the query string
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
            }

            command.Prepare();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return getResult(dr);
            }
        }
    }
}

public string GetMySpecId(string dataId)
{
    return ExecuteQuery(
        dr =>
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                return dr[0].ToString();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        },
        "select \"specId\" from \"MyTable\" where \"dataId\" = @dataId",
        new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "@dataId", dataId } });
}
```

P.S. - the `@` before the string in your example is just an escape sequence used in C#.